# Create a Dataframe in Dask

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask, dask-dataframe

I'm just starting using Dask as a possible replacement (?) of pandas. The first think that hit me is that i can't seem to find a way to create a dataframe from a couple lists/arrays.

In regular pandas i just do: `pd.DataFrame({'a':a,'b':b,...})` but i can't find an equivalent way to do it in Dask, other than create the df in pandas and then create a dask df with `from_pandas()`.

Is there any way? Or the only way is literally to create the df in pandas and then "import" it into a dask df?

Comment: yep. dask.dataframe is built on top of pandas. that's a good way to go. there are other ways referenced in the docs - you can use [`dask.dataframe.from_dask_array`](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/generated/dask.dataframe.from_dask_array.html) if you have an array you'd like to create it from. do you have an example in mind?

Comment: Also - definitely don’t recommend dask as a replacement for pandas. Dask is the heavier, more difficult, slower-for-small-problems-faster-and-more-powerful-for-big-operations cousin of pandas. But you absolutely need to continue using pandas if you want to use dask.dataframe. See the [best practices](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/dataframe-best-practices.html) guide for more info, esp the first section: “use pandas”

Comment: Well, yeah, what you just wrote pretty much summarized my general situation... i'm not so sure now of how much worth it's to switch. Thought the multicore thing could give me some improvement in performance, but yeah, i'm seeing it's more of a problem to use.

Comment: just to clarify - I'm a huge fan of dask. I use it every day for my job. but my job entails working with many terrabytes of climate data. if your problem fits comfortably within memory, dask is probably not worth it, unless you need to parallelize a job that is heavily compute-bound and you can't make use of numpy multithreading.

Comment: Absolutely, my dfs probably barely hit a couple megabytes, but i do a lot of subsetting, loop iterations over the entire frame, etc., and thought i could maybe cut a couple seconds with dask, but yeah, it seems on small data it's ~0.

Comment: yeah, and looping over the whole frame is particularly bad for dask. dask.dataframe is just a collection of pandas.Dataframes kit together with a scheduler. So anything requiring communication across partitions is going to be much slower on a dask dataframe than in pandas. You could see acceleration on small dataframes if all your operations are CPU-intensive and row-specific, such as doing geospatial operations on each row independently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a fairly recent feature by @MrPowers that allows creating `dask.DataFrame` using [`from_dict` method](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.DataFrame.from_dict.html):

```py
from dask.dataframe import DataFrame
ddf = DataFrame.from_dict({"num1": [1, 2, 3], "num2": [7, 8, 9]}, npartitions=2)
```

However, note that this method is meant for more concise `dask.DataFrame` code when used in tutorials and code examples, so when working with real datasets it's better to use more appropriate methods, e.g. `read_csv` or `read_parquet`.

Comment: Literally what i was looking for, thanks a LOT!. I use dataframes to store generated data inside scripts, rarely reading from files.